# How to delete certain characters of a word in c#

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a

```
string word = "degree/NN";
```

What I want is to remove the `"/NN"` part of the word and take only the word `"degree"`.

I have following conditions:

- The length of the word can be different in different occasions. (can be any word therefore the length is not fixed)
- But the word will contain the `"/NN"` part at the end always.

How can I do this in C# .NET?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implemented as an extension method:

```
static class StringExtension
{
  public static string RemoveTrailingText(this string text, string textToRemove)
  {
    if (!text.EndsWith(textToRemove))
      return text;

    return text.Substring(0, text.Length - textToRemove.Length);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
string whatever = "degree/NN".RemoveTrailingText("/NN");
```

This takes into account that the unwanted part "/NN" is only removed from the end of the word, as you specified. A simple `Replace` would remove every occurrence of "/NN". However, that might not be a problem in your special case.

Answer (score 4):

You can shorten the input string by three characters using [String.Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.remove.aspx) like this:

```
string word = "degree/NN";

string result = word.Remove(word.Length - 3);
```

If the part after the slash has variable length, you can use [String.LastIndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof.aspx) to find the slash:

```
string word = "degree/NN";

string result = word.Remove(word.LastIndexOf('/'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use

```
word = word.Replace(@"/NN","");
```

**edit**

Forgot to add word =. Fixed that in my example.

Comment: Agreed - and just to clarify if you're a beginner, you need to set word = word.Replace(@"/NN","");

Comment: Harsh to call me a beginner because I forgot to add word =, but thats your choice...

Comment: actually this won't work so great if there is a chance that "/NN" will appear more than one time inside text, i.e. consider string "c/NNeee/NN"

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
  string.replace();
```

if you need to replace patterns use regex replace

```
  Regex rgx = new Regex("/NN");
  string result = rgx.Replace("degree/NN", string.Empty);
```

Comment: I did try this but it gave me an error saying that I am missing an assembly reference for Regex.